# Propositional Logic Help: $(\neg p \wedge (p \vee q)) \rightarrow q $ is a tautology

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, formal-proofs

I need to prove that $(\neg p \wedge (p \vee q)) \rightarrow q $ is a tautology using Laws of Logic (not truth tables).

This is what I tried:

$\equiv (( \neg p \wedge p) \vee (\neg p  \wedge q)) \rightarrow q \\
\equiv (F \vee (\neg p  \wedge q)) \rightarrow q \\
\equiv (\neg p  \wedge q) \rightarrow q \\
\equiv (F) \rightarrow  q \\
\equiv T $

Is this logically correct?
The laws I used in order were: Distributive, then negation, and identity. My only issue is with the last step where I know the truth values of $(\neg p  \wedge q)$ are all $F$ but I dont know what law it uses.

Please Help!

Comment: $\neg p\land q$ can have either truth value; it need not be $F$. Do you have $p\to q\equiv \neg p\lor q$?

Comment: As Brian M. Scott points out, $\neg p\land q$ may be either $T$ or $F$. My answer gives you a *strong* hint on how to use the equivalences you deduced so far to end up with your tautology. :)

Comment: @induktio Thanks a lot! I forgot about manipulating the $\rightarrow$ symbol.

Comment: @DigitalShrapnel Does it make sense now?

Comment: @induktio Yeah. I just need to backtrack to fully understand how $\neg p \wedge q$ is operated on. But I see where it leads.

Comment: @DigitalShrapnel It's DeMorgan: $\neg(\neg p\land q)\equiv p\lor \neg q$. :)

Comment: @induktio Oh I knew that, but Im unsure about how the $\rightarrow q$ becomes $\vee q$.

Comment: @DigitalShrapnel Oh. Then you're pretty much done! That's *very* simple. Write out the truth table to see that $p\to q \equiv \neg p\lor q$. And you're done!

Comment: @induktio Do you rearrange $(\neg p \wedge q) \rightarrow q$ as $q \wedge (\neg p \rightarrow q)$. I mean what are you negating? I feel like Im very close to understanding!

Comment: $(\neg p\land q)\to q$ is of the form $r\to j$. Now you negate, getting that $\neg (r\to j) \equiv \neg(\neg r\lor j)\equiv r\land \neg j$. Now use $r: \neg p\land q$ and $j : q$ to get the same thing.

Comment: @DigitalShrapnel That is, you get $$(\neg p\land q)\to q\equiv \neg(\neg p\land q)\lor q\equiv (p\lor \neg q)\lor q \equiv p\lor(\neg q\lor q) .$$

Comment: Oh so you are treating the $(\neg p \wedge q) \rightarrow q$ as you would $p \rightarrow q$, when you swap it out?

Comment: Right (if I am understanding your question correctly). In general, if you are trying to prove a complicated implication or some other propositional form that is complicated, you want to treat it as being composed of many parts. So in your problem, start off by thinking of $\Omega\to\Phi\equiv\neg\Omega\lor\Phi$, where $\Omega : (\neg p\land q)$ and $\Phi : q$.

Comment: @induktio Awesome! I solved it last night. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @DigitalShrapnel Good job! I hope I answered your question effectively :)

Comment: See also: [prove $[¬p\land (p\lor q)]→q ≡ T$ without using the truth table](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/979604)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** We have that
$$
(\neg p \land q)\to q \equiv (p\lor \neg q)\lor q \equiv p \lor (\neg q\lor q). 
$$
You should be able to take it from there.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since my discrete class, but here's my try. It looks like all you really need to use is the simple Elimination Rule, which states:

$p \wedge q \rightarrow p$

OR (stay with me)

$p \wedge q \rightarrow q$

---

So, to finish off the last part of your problem:

$\equiv (\neg p  \wedge q) \rightarrow q \\
\equiv q \rightarrow q \\$

Or, heck: 
$\equiv (\neg p  \wedge q) \rightarrow q \\
\equiv \neg p \rightarrow q \\$

---

Here's a clean, handy [cheat sheet](http://www.tjhsst.edu/~rlatimer/ai/Logic/logicTable/node1.html) that may help you out. One thing I remember is it's easy getting caught up in what the values of p and q *may* be, when what's important in "proofs" like these is establishing a *route* to truth. Thinking that way helped me out.